# Is there a way to run an Add-In from a project template wizard?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins, visual-studio-templates

I have created a new DataObject project template, and I have an Add-In that generates new data object classes and adds them to the current project. Is there a way that I can make the add-in run whenever the project template is used?

-edit-
I figured it out. This question can be closed, except I don't like any of those close reasons. The template wizard has access to the DTE object and an add-in can be called by its command via the DTE2.ExecuteCommand method.